# Extracted tables from PDF returned incorrect data - Python

Tags: python, csv, pdf, extract

I've tried many times to find a way to import this data from this PDF.

(http://www.imea.com.br/upload/publicacoes/arquivos/16032018194928.pdf) It's a report from a agri department in Brazil. I need just the first one.

My mission is to develop a program that gets some specific points of this report and build a paragraph with it.

The thing is that I couldn't find a way to import the table correctly.

I've tried to use tabula-py, but didn't work very well.

Does anyone know how can I import it?

Python 3.6 / Mac hight Sierra

ps: It need to be done just with python, because this code will be upload at Heroku, so I can't install softwares there. (BTW, I think even the tabula-py would not work there as I need to have Java installed... but I will try anyway)

Here what I tried:

```
    import tabula
    import requests

    url = "http://www.imea.com.br/upload/publicacoes/arquivos/16032018194928.pdf"
    response = requests.get(url)
    df = tabula.read_pdf(url)
    tabula.convert_into("teste.pdf", "output.csv", output_format="csv", area=(67.14, 23.54,284.12, 558.01)) #I tried also without area.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think tabula expects a file, not a URL. Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                                                                                                                                         

import tabula
import requests

url = "http://www.imea.com.br/upload/publicacoes/arquivos/16032018194928.pdf"
filename = "16032018194928.pdf"
response = requests.get(url)
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
df = tabula.read_pdf(filename)
print(df)
```